# Onde colocar os modelos matemáticos no Django

Tags: python, django

Sou iniciante no assunto, então perdoem a ignorância.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando python no Django, onde a partir de dados informados pelo usuário a aplicação irá retornar certos valores.

Porém estou na duvida onde coloco minhas fórmulas matemáticas. Se posso colocar dentro da pasta models.py e crio uma função dentro da classe.. por exemplo:

```
class Consumo(models.Model):
    media_anual = models.CharField('Média anual de consumo', max_length=5)
    (...)
    
    def formula1:
    (...)
```

se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu adoto a prática de colocar nos models os métodos que dependem de algum tipo de interação com o Django e com o banco de dados, ali são feitas as consultas e preparação de parâmetros.

Os Cálculos, fórmulas, etc. eu coloco em outros arquivos, sendo que estes arquivos ficam "puros" sem elementos do Django. Estas funções (ou métodos) recebem os parâmetros, mas nunca models.

Adotei esta prática porque facilita o desenvolvimento em geral, o debug e a implementação de testes unitários. Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma função que realiza um determinado cálculos eu posso desenvolver e testar ela diretamente passando parâmetros de teste, sem precisar importar o Django (que é demorado), sem precisar lidar com as dependências do Django e sem precisar lidar com models, fazer mocks e coisas do tipo.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Vou fazer desse modo, agradeço demais